# Navigating to wpf page based on timer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, timer, navigation

I'm trying to navigate to a different page from my MainWindow in a WPF application.  The MainWindow just has some welcome text and I want it to move to another page after 4 seconds.  The timer is working just fine but I am getting an error that says,

"Error  1   'UbiTutorial.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Frame' and no extension method 'Frame' accepting a first argument of type 'UbiTutorial.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\thomas\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\UbiTutorial\UbiTutorial\MainWindow.xaml.cs    54  22  UbiTutorial"

in my method

```
if (introTime > 4)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Touch));
}
```

Visual Studio is complaining about the Frame part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Frame` is a Control Type not a Control Instance, without seeing your Xaml I have no idea of what the name of the Frame that you added is, it probably defaulted to `frame1` that is what you will need to use to access the Navigate Method. Hopefully this will give you an idea.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Frame Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="frame1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
     /// <summary>
     /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
     /// </summary>
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
     {
         DispatcherTimer introTime = new DispatcherTimer();
         public MainWindow()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
             introTime.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
             introTime.Tick += new EventHandler(introTime_Tick);
             introTime.Start();
         }

         void introTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             //this.frame1.Navigate(new Uri(@"http://www.google.com"));
             this.frame1.Navigate(new UserControl1());
         }
     }
 }
```

**UserControl1.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="Red" >
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have gotten that to work.  My next step is to navigate to addition pages based on events on the current page in the frame.  Once the user has accomplished something, load the next page.  Specifically, if a user has touchedDown on the page for 5 seconds, load the next page.  Is there a way to pass the frame as a parameter to each page so that I can put the code in the current page to load the next page, or is rather is it done by returning information back from the current page to the MainWindow telling it to load a new page onto the frame? Thank you! @mark-hall

Comment: @ThomasCrosley Are you using MVVM or just code behind? Personally I would let the MainWindow handle it, have your Page raise an Event and use that to determine when to swap pages.

Comment: I am just using code behind.  Would you recommended using MVVM?  I liked the MainWindow approach as well, especially if I someday want to get rid a page of or swap their order.

Comment: @ThomasCrosley There will be a learning curve for MVVM, for right now depending on the complexity of your application code behind in your MainForm would probably be the best way to go. I would make each page its own entity and pass values in by Properties / Methods and get data out by using events to pass the information back into your MainMenu. It is my opinion that a class should stand on its own not requiring special knowledge of the internals of another class to function.